# Legend not removed when layer changed

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto, legend, debugging

I made [this webpage](http://omars.me.pn/PoSERU282014.html) with JavaScript and CartoDB.

The layer selector works like I expected it to but I noticed that the legend are stacking on top of each other and not being removed when the layer is changed. I tried a few different things but to no avail.

A few posts on the internet also relate to a possible bug in CartoDB that may be causing this. Anyone have experience with this?

If you open the map switch layers several times then examine the DOM you will see that the **map.remove();** option is not **totally** clearing all elements of the layers for the previous selection.

Example:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  To assist potential answerers to help you I would recommend always including your code snippets as text rather than pictures.  The format **`{}`** button makes this easy to do.

Comment: this is a known bug: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/75

Comment: Looks like it's working now, right?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bug as @Javi Santana says in the comments, but it's been fixed already and your map seems to be behaving as expected :-)